# Grafana https protocol

Tags: linux, ubuntu, http, https, grafana

Я использую Grafana на своем сервере. Разворачивается она просто, не через docker.

Проблема в том что раньше она работала по протоколу http, я захотел перейти на https
В grafana.ini я создал следующие строки:

```
#cert_file = /etc/grafana/cert.pem
#cert_key = /etc/grafana/key.pem
```

И указал протокол https. Сертификат создал командой ubuntu.
При подключении сайт пишет что подключение не защищено.

Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

Comment: «Сертификат создал» — и у браузера нет никаких оснований доверять такому левому сертификату. Чтобы подключение считалось защищённым, приобретите сертификат у какого-нибудь из доверенных центров сертификации, например Let's Encrypt

Comment: А разве нельзя сделать сертификат доверенным?

Comment: На странице «подключение не защищено» должна быть кнопка добавления исключения, да

Comment: все же хочется каким то образом в ubuntu сделать сертификат доверенных чтобы не было предупреждения

Comment: Ну если у вас аллергия на проверенные центры сертификации, то https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450

Comment: подскажите еще пожалуйста какое расширение правильное для сертификата?
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout grafana.pem -out grafana_2.pem верная команда?

Comment: параметры конфига, который начинаютс с `#` игнорируются. но все равно так работать не будет, я написал ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сертификат нужно генерировать не самому, а через lets encrypt. А чтобы он обновлялся автоматически, надо использовать certbot.

У меня есть готовый скрипт для этого, но он требует, чтобы ваш домен находился на cloudflare. Потому что используется api cloudflare для подтверждения домена при обновлении сертификата.

Для начала вам нужно сгенерировать токен https://dash.cloudflare.com/profile/api-tokens в cloudflare с правами редактирования домена, на котором работает grafana.
Созданный токен сохраните в переменную:

```
# сюда подставьте свой токен
export TOKEN="h6N8z2L4HU4xvoJzKdPD8wTURW0SeSeWRLeI-NGk"
```

Ваш домен так же нужно сохранить в переменную:

```
# сюда подставьте свой домен
export DOMAIN="example.com"
```

Если вы используете субдомен, тогда его тоже нужно указать в значении домена:

```
export DOMAIN="grafana.example.com"
```

Дальше просто выполните такой скрипт:

```
apt install certbot python3-pip -y
pip3 install certbot-dns-cloudflare

mkdir ~/.certbot
printf "# Cloudflare API token used by Certbot\ndns_cloudflare_api_token = $TOKEN" > ~/.certbot/cloudflare.ini
chmod 600 ~/.certbot/cloudflare.ini

certbot certonly \
  --dns-cloudflare \
  --dns-cloudflare-credentials ~/.certbot/cloudflare.ini \
  --dns-cloudflare-propagation-seconds 60 \
  -d $DOMAIN
```

После последней команды certbot будет задавать нам вопросы:

- Вопрос `Enter email address` - надо ввести почту администратора, именно вашу личную, чтобы получать уведомления от Lets Encrypt.
- Вопрос `Please read the Terms of Service at...` - надо ввести `A`.
- Вопрос `Would you be willing...` - надо ввести `N`

Если все хорошо, сертификат будет сохранен в файлах:

- `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem`
- `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem`

Перемещать эти файлы нельзя, потому что они будут автоматически обновляться в это место.

В вашем конфиге grafana нужно указать путь к этому сертификату:

```
cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
cert_key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```

Чтобы сертификат пересоздавался автоматически, нужно добавить такую команду в `crontab -e`:

```
0 3  *   *   *     certbot renew
```